# How to calculate optimum feature numbers in PCA (Python)?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

I'm performing PCA preprocessing on a dataset of 78 variables. How would I calculate the optimal value of PCA variables?

- My first thought was to start at, for example, 5 and working my way up and calculating accuracy . However, for obvious reasons this wasn't a time effective means of calculating.

Does anyone have any suggestions/experience? Or even a methodology for calculating the optimal value?

Comment: Do you mean n_components? I always plot cumulative variance vs n components then use elbow method. see here: https://www.mikulskibartosz.name/pca-how-to-choose-the-number-of-components/. Try on few datapoints and get the optimal value using the method mentioned as above.

Answer (score 4):

First look at the dataset distribution and then used `explained_variance_` to find the number of components.

- 1. Start with projecting your samples on a 2-D graph.

  - Assume I have a face dataset (Olivetti-faces) 40 people and each person has 10 samples. Overall 400 images. We will split 280 trains and 120 test samples.
  - ```py
    from sklearn.datasets import fetch_olivetti_faces
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


    olivetti = fetch_olivetti_faces()

    x = olivetti.images  # Train
    y = olivetti.target  # Labels

    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y,
                                                        test_size=0.3,
                                                        random_state=42)

    x_train = x_train.reshape((x_train.shape[0], x.shape[1] * x.shape[2]))
    x_test = x_test.reshape((x_test.shape[0], x.shape[1] * x.shape[2]))
    x = x.reshape((x.shape[0]), x.shape[1] * x.shape[2])
    ```
  - Now we want to see how pixels are distributed. To understand clearly, we will display the pixels in a 2-D graph.
  - ```py
    from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
    from matplotlib.pyplot import figure, get_cmap, colorbar, show

    class_num = 40
    sample_num = 10

    pca = PCA(n_components=2).fit_transform(x)
    idx_range = class_num * sample_num
    fig = figure(figsize=(6, 3), dpi=300)
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
    c_map = get_cmap(name='jet', lut=class_num)
    scatter = ax.scatter(pca[:idx_range, 0], pca[:idx_range, 1], 
                         c=y[:idx_range],s=10, cmap=c_map)

    ax.set_xlabel("First Principal Component")
    ax.set_ylabel("Second Principal Component")
    ax.set_title("PCA projection of {} people".format(class_num))
    colorbar(mappable=scatter)
    show()
    ```
  - [image]
  - We can say 40 people, each with 10 samples are not distinguishable with only 2 principal components.
  - Please remember we created this graph from the main dataset, neither train nor test.
- How are many principal components we need to clearly distinguish the data?

  - To answer the above question we will be using `explained_variance_`.
  - From the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html):

    > The amount of variance explained by each of the selected components. Equal to n_components largest eigenvalues of the covariance matrix of X.
  - ```py
    from matplotlib.pyplot import plot, xlabel, ylabel

    pca2 = PCA().fit(x)
    plot(pca2.explained_variance_, linewidth=2)
    xlabel('Components')
    ylabel('Explained Variaces')
    show()
    ```
  - [image]
  - From the above graph, we can see after 100 components PCA distinguishes the people.

Simplified-code:

---

```py
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_olivetti_faces
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x, _ = fetch_olivetti_faces(return_X_y=True)
pca2 = PCA().fit(x)
plt.plot(pca2.explained_variance_, linewidth=2)
plt.xlabel('Components')
plt.ylabel('Explained Variances')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will loop through different number of components, and tell us how can components are necessary while maintaining correct value of variance

```
def bestComponentValue(spotifyDataNumCols):
    for i in range(2,len(spotifyDataNumCols.columns)):
        numData = spotifyDataNumCols.loc[:,spotifyDataNumCols.columns].values
        pca = PCA(n_components = i)
        pca.fit_transform(numData)
        print(f'components = {i}, {pca.explained_variance_ratio_.sum()}')
        

bestComponentValue(spotifyDataNumCols)
```

> Output:

- components = 2, 0.5790925972563609
- components = 3, 0.6901349034009403
- components = 4, 0.7918360969456241
- components = 5, 0.8648628189138532
- components = 6, 0.9067382436742328
- components = 7, 0.9390706979145478
- components = 8, 0.9632382232624446
- components = 9, 0.9829405984034115
- components = 10, 0.9970869735509401